# Removing Blank Lines From TCP Listener Network Stream

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, tcplistener

I'm currently pulling XML data from a NVR CCTV Machine.
I am using a [TCP Listener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the data and because I dont know the size of the bytes I have combined the `TCP Listener` with a [Network Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx) as some clients might have more cameras than others.
Whenever a connection is made to the NVR machine, I append all data it receives via the `TcpListener`  to a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to speed things up and use less resources because as I said before, some clients will have more or less cameras than others and the XML data can become very long.
Here is `GetTcpStreamResult IEnumerable<String>` that's pulling the data and returning it to the classes `StringBuilder`

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetTcpStreamResults
{
    get
    {
        Byte[] bytes;
        this.TcpListener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Listening");
        TcpClient client = TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Made");
        while (true)
        {

            using (NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream())
            {
                if (client.ReceiveBufferSize > 0)
                {
                    bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    ns.Read(bytes, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    yield return String.Format(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once the class is created `TCPListener` and the command is given, It will begin listening.

```
public async Task<bool> StartListeningAsync()
{
    foreach (string value in GetTcpStreamResults)
    {
        this.Xml.AppendLine(value);
    }
    return await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Here is the `main` static void of how I'm calling the `TCPListener` Class I've created.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TCPListener TcpListener = new TCPListener(port:23);
        Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await TcpListener.StartListeningAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(TcpListener.Xml.ToString());
                TcpListener.Xml.Clear();
            }
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here is the `Stringbuilder` string result (I've had to remove some of the XML Data because its simply too long to post
This is one of 20 camera's data

`Listening`

```
<3 ConnectState="Connected" ConnectState="Loss" Sub="Loss" RW="---------" 
Redundancy="---------">
<Alarm Type="Local alarm" Times="0" CurAlarmState="Normal"></Alarm>
<Alarm Type="Network alarm" Times="0" CurAlarmState="Normal"></Alarm>
<Alarm Type="Motion detection" Times="0" CurAlarmState="Normal"></Alarm>
<Alarm Type="Video loss" Times="0" CurAlarmState="Normal"></Alarm>
<Alarm Type="Camera masking" Times="0" CurAlarmState="Normal"></Alarm>
<Alarm Type="Cross detect" Times="0" CurAlarmState="Normal"></Alarm>
<Alarm Type="Intrusion detect" Times="0" CurAlarmState="Normal"></Alarm>
</3>
```

`Listening`
`(Code Above Will Repeat As The NVR machine sends out its data every 60 seconds)`

How can I remove the blank lines at the bottom of the `Stringbuilder` data so I dont have massive gaps between data pulls because once the data is all in order, 
I will convert the string to a [XML Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) and then to a [XmlAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.name(v=vs.110).aspx) so I can create another class
I have tried the following with no success.

```
static void Main()
{
    TCPListener TcpListener = new TCPListener(port:23);
    Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await TcpListener.StartListeningAsync();
            string resultString = Regex.Replace(TcpListener.Xml.ToString(), @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            Console.WriteLine(resultString);
            TcpListener.Xml.Clear();
        }
    });
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And Also

```
using (NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream())
{
     if (client.ReceiveBufferSize > 0)
     {
          bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
          ns.Read(bytes, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
          if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)))
          {
              yield return String.Format(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
          }
     }
     break;
}
```

But its still gets the same results.

Comment: Dont use writeline to your string builder..

Comment: @BugFinder, Noted, However still the same results unfortunately

Comment: That `while(true)` looks like it could be missed. The body does an optional yield and will _always_ `break` in the first round.

Comment: Yeah, from one reason or another, if the `break` isnt there, nothing gets returned. So i figured it would only go to it if the `client.ReceiveBufferSize` was equal to 0

Comment: normally you act on bytes read not the buffer size.... so while((i = ns.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0)   then if no data is read nothing happens..

Comment: @BugFinder Followed your advice, however the blank lines are still there after the data.

Comment: then it strongly suggests some data is being sent

Comment: so its quite possible that the data being sent in the first place by the machine are blank lines?, I noticed in the Debug output window, there are no blank lines? is this normal not to show blank lines?

Comment: Why are you repeatably starting the  await TcpListener.StartListeningAsync(); inside a while loop.  You should only need to start the Async Listener once.

Comment: @jdweng if I dont when it clears the results, it will just loop over and over, at least when the await task is there, it will wait for a connection

Comment: Why do you need a await on a Async method?  Why do you need a while loop on a Asyn method?  See the msdn example for sockets : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: @jdweng I took your advice and started only listening once, I also removed the while true part which meant I was able to remove the break, I tried the class in a form application with a rich text box and what do you know, there are no massive spaces have the data anymore